# Why is my R graphics device not refreshing and gets drawn so slowly through VNC?

Tags: x11, vnc, r

The plotting speed of the graphics device is extremely slow when I use a VNC connection. The rest of the connection works perfectly fine so I cannot blame the network, it is specifically R devices that take years to plot plus they do not refresh. If I move a window above my R device it erases the content, I need to resize the R device window so it gets redrawn. If I directly connect with ssh, all is good.

Is there a way to prevent this or am I missing some fundamentals of the mode I am working with?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. Very simple one but not related to the fundamentals of using R through VNC, the problem was a combination of an old vncserver version and a funny network triangulation. Case closed.